# Build a document-term matrix from a list of documents, each of which is in list form

Tags: python, term-document-matrix

I wonder if there exists an elegant way to convert a list of documents to a document-term matrix. The motivation to do this is the need of subtle transformation on the terms from documents, i.e., stemming. 
the input data is like

```
[['tom','want','apple'],['tom','love','pear']]
```

output data should be a matrix or whatever data type that can be easily converted to a numpy.array. Just like:

```
[[1,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1,1]]
```

What I have now is join every element in the outer list and then use `CountVectorizer` in `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`. But it is inefficient to do that for a large corpus.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
data = [['tom','want','apple'],['tom','love','pear']]
mlb.fit_transform(data)
```

Return

```
array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
      [0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

Note: the documents are sorted in alphabetical order.

```
mlb.classes_
>>> array(['apple', 'love', 'pear', 'tom', 'want'])
```